# Is providing location an issue?

Tags: anonymity, location

I (newbie) am giving tor a test drive, picked meetup.com. The first thing that site (http://meetup.com) asks you for is your location (city). Is this bad, not recommended, no problem, ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will of course reduce your anonymity (potentially catastrophically) but if you don't require anonymity for the service itself then it is not a problem to use Tor for your normal day-to-day browsing. What you should do is **always** make use of the "New Identity" functionality of Tor Browser (located under the green onion menu) to ensure a clean break between browsing sessions.

If you don't do this, traditional tracking methods may link your identity on the site in question to browsing you intend to be unlinkable to you. So if you don't need anonymity, ensure you perform "New Identity" before you start using the webpage (to ensure you don't drag contamination *into* the session with you), then use "New Identity" again once you're finished using that service (to ensure you don't drag contamination *out of* the session with you).

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on the reason you're using Tor :

- Yes, it is an issue, if you're about to be untrackable for a reason of self-survival, for example. You don't want people who are censoring the Web to know where to find you to take you down
- No, it's not an issue, if you're using Tor as a tamper-resistant transport, i.e. for connecting to Facebook's onion entry point from a public Wi-Fi hotspot : you're fine with your location tags, you just don't want somebody to tap your passoword from it.

You actually should diecide for yourself